Python, упрощение условия if-а
Может вопрос не совсем коректный, но всё же, вот код:
n=int(input())
dl_list1=[]
dl_list2=[]
lst = [input().split() for i in range(n)]

for j in range(1,n+1):
    top=lst[j-1][j:-j]
    bottom=lst[-j][j:-j]

    if (top or bottom) == []:
        break
    dl_list1.append(top)
    dl_list2.append(bottom)

print(dl_list1)
print('\n')
print(dl_list2)

Вопрос, пайчарм ругается, что можно упростить условие в 10-ой строке, вот оно:
if (top or bottom) == []:

Не совсем понимаю, каким образом это можно сделать?

А он не предлагает вариантов? Наверное if not (top or bottom): break

Да, спасибо. Нет, вариантов не предлагал.

...
if not (top or bottom):
    break
...


пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
